# Greek is not showing properly (API)

Tags: r, json, api, httr

I 'm trying to read [this json data](https://anaptyxi.gov.gr/GetData.ashx?queryType=projects_v2&perioxesMode=0&selectedPerioxes%5B%5D=48) from [here](http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset/espa-2014-2020-pra3eis-ana-perifereia-peloponnhsoy). I use the code below:

```
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("jsonlite")
library("httr")
library("jsonlite")

res = GET("https://anaptyxi.gov.gr/GetData.ashx?queryType=projects_v2&perioxesMode=0&selectedPerioxes[]=48")
res
rawToChar(res$content)
data <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
names(data)
data$Records
```

The problem is that Greek text is not showing properly. It's a mess:
[image]

What can I do about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I ran your code it worked and the Greek characters showed correctly when I typed View(data$Records) - the code was copy and pasted so it should produce the same results. Did you do this within RStudio or some other way?

Comment: I run again the same code, but I have the same problems. I can't see correctly Greek characters by using `View(data$Records)`.  I see the same mess as the picture.

Comment: Can you try Sys.getlocale()

Comment: I tried `Sys.getlocale()`. I got the message `"LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253"`

Comment: I tried to update R and (I believe...) problem solved. One more question: I that picture (https://im.ge/i/FDJqfS) the one you see using `View(data$Records)`?